# TCP/IP Connection error when connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics, knime

When I try and connect to the SQL Server database, I get this error :

> The TCP/IP connection to the host P5CPAJJDAD01.CORP.AD.CTC, port 1433 has failed.
>
> Error: Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall

I can access the database using Python and also MS Access database. I'm trying to use KNIME (an analytics tool) to connect with the database but it throws that error. Which is odd considering that I can access the exact same database using Python and MS Access.

Could this be a security issue?

Comment: Have a look at the SQL Server logs and check what the actual error is.

Comment: I get that error when I try to connect using KNIME. I'm able to access using MS SQL Server Mgt Studio and MS Access and also with Python. So I don't have any "log files" generated with KNIME as it doesn;t even establish the connection.

Comment: I'm asking you to check SQL Server's logs, not KNIME's.

Comment: Are Access and SSMS connecting using the TCP/IP driver as well, or the Named Pipes driver? If they're using the TCP/IP driver are they using a different port? tcp/1433 is only the default port - it can be moved anywhere, especially for Named Instances.

Comment: SSMS and Python are accessing data via port 1433. Its frustrating because KNIME saves me a lot of time on some analytical operations w/o having to code in Python or write queries, and I'm unable to use it

Comment: Which KNIME version are you using, which driver and what node?

Comment: Knime version - 4.0.0, Driver - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver, Node- SQL Server Connector

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? If so check [here](https://www.knime.com/faq#q24). Also what kind of authentication are you using? Can you share your URL structure?

Comment: This is the connection string: jdbc:sqlserver://<host_name>:1433;databaseName=<db_name>;integratedSecurity=true Also don't think I'm behind a firewall because I can access the database just fine using Acess, MSSMS and even Python!

Comment: Have tried using JDBC authentication and also SQL login but to no avail!

Comment: If you are using new SQL Connector (without legacy in name) integratedSecurity parameter should be specified under JDBC Parameters tab and not into URL. As a workaround you can try using Python Integration in KNIME to bring data into it and perform operations you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In JDBC parameters, I type in 'integratedSecurity' under name and "True" in Value? (Type = Literal Value)? Is that how we give the parameters? That doesn't work :(

Comment: JDBC parameters are driver dependent so check documentation but seems ok. Don't know if values are case sensitive...